# "Явь" как синоним "действительности"

Tags: значение-слов

"Я убедился в яви этого события"

Можно так сказать? Словари говорят о схожести значений. Но я не припоминаю примеров употребления. Мне встречалось только так: "Мы убедились в действительности существования (чего-то там)". А вот на "явь" "действительность" заменить можно?

Мне вспоминается похожее по смыслу выражение "наяву".

Просьба не давать советов о перестройке предложения и замене слов. Вопрос не практический, а условный. Интересует именно одно: можно ли вложить в "явь" такой смысл или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, так сказать *нельзя*, поскольку "**явь**" - это категория *чувственного восприятия* (противоположность *сну*, *бреду* и прочим формам состояния сознания: = мне это не снится, а *я вижу это собственными глазами или отчётливо слышу*), а **действительность** чего-либо - (умственное) *суждение* о событии или о существовании чего-либо. Таковы же по смыслу и родственные слова: "**явственность**" (от "явственный") означает *отчётливость* видимого или слышимого ("*он явственно услышал*"). Видимо, поэтому предложенный пример и звучит странно, во всяком случае, вне поэтических вольностей.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ли вложить смысл "действительности" в *явь*? Да, так как налицо синонимичность этих понятий согласно многим словарям.

Однако слово "явь" явно дает дополнительный оттенок так как *явь* и *действительность* могут употребляться вместе ([плеоназм)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC). Пример:

> Осязательно обличились отношения и поверхности предметов; в широких кругозорах охватывал взгляд всю пеструю **явь действительности** и разглядел за океаном очертания неведомых земель.
>
> [Вяч. Иванов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), "Шекспир и Сервантес".

Также встречаются примеры употребления *явь происходящего*, хотя я, субъективно, не отнес бы их к абсолютно обоснованным и стилистически корректным.

Comment: Думаю, в обоих примерах (они допустимы), "явь действительности" (проявление д.) и "явь происходящего" (видимость или очевидность п.), "явь" далека от _синонима_ "действительности". Словари много чего объявляют синонимами, но взаимозаменяемости слов это не гарантирует.